# ClickableSpan loses its click when changing any device configuration with another view on top

Tags: android

I'm using the SpannableString and the ClickableSpan to edit my string and it works very well.
Although, when I click on the text, it opens another view, a popupWindow, and if I change the device language, for instance, with the popupWindow opened, when I return to the app, my text loses the underlined and the click, and does not back to work, only if I exit the app and return again.

I don't know if is a ClickableSpan issue, or something. Has anyone seen something like that?

My code to apply the click:

```
     SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(message);
 StyleSpan privacyPolicyStyle = new StyleSpan(
    android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
ClickableSpan privacyPolicySpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
    // Opens my popupWindow. 
           //I use the getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() as view to show it
    }
};
spannableString.setSpan(privacyPolicyStyle, 1,
    10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(privacyPolicySpan, 1,
    10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

txvTermsMessage.setText(spannableString);
txvTermsMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Is there any code path in which you update `txvTermsMessage` without going through your `SpannableString` logic? Have you retrieved the text from `txvTermsMessage` after encountering the problem and seen if your span is still in place?

Comment: No, I only set txvTermsMessage content this time. Do you mean, set the textView content again, without use those codes?

Comment: I am just trying to help you determine if the problem is that the `SpannableString` is losing its spans (in which case, you could detect this), or if you are accidentally replacing it with something that does not have the spans, or if the `SpannableString` seems fine but is just not rendering properly.

Comment: Using the getSpanStart/End it returns my character's position normally. Also, after every device config change, the Android recreates the app, and my objects. Would this change anything? If it's a rendering problem, how to fix it?

Comment: "Would this change anything?" -- it might lose your `LinkMovementMethod`. While obvious stuff, like the text in a `TextView`, is retained on a configuration change, I do not know if a movement method is. Then again, I don't know if that is even needed to allow the clicks to work. "If it's a rendering problem, how to fix it?" -- you probably can't, which is why I am hoping that it is something else. :-)

Comment: I see. Well, another thing I've observed is that if I don't open the popupWindow, even with the config change, the click works properly. Perhaps, the textView is losing the LinkMovementMethod, as you said.

Comment: Try calling `setMovementMethod()` every time that you are inflating the layout, rather than just when you are populating the `TextView`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I've had to change the implementation. Now, I'm using the OnClickListener and it works very well. It might be an Android issue.     Thanks for the help @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it handling the `onTouch` event of the textView myself. You have to add this listener to your textview (it does basically the same as `LinkMovementMethod` `onTouch` method)

```
txvTermsMessage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) v;
                Object text = textView.getText();

                if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                    Spanned buffer = (Spanned) text;

                    int action = event.getAction();

                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                          || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                        int x = (int) event.getX();
                        int y = (int) event.getY();

                        x -= textView.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                        y -= textView.getTotalPaddingTop();

                        x += textView.getScrollX();
                        y += textView.getScrollY();

                        Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
                        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                        ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,
                              ClickableSpan.class);

                        if (link.length != 0) {
                            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                link[0].onClick(textView);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

As we don't need the `LinkMovementMethod` to handle touch events anymore, you can remove this line:

```
txvTermsMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```